# How to self-terminate a bash script after timeout?

Tags: bash, process, kill, signals

I have a bash script doing a lot of things called `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#It
#Is
#Doing
#Things
```

Is there a way that I can get the process ID of this script from within itself, and then kill it after 5 minutes?

Like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Get pid of script.sh here, start a 5 minute timer and kill the script after time runs out
#It
#Is
#Doing
#Things
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem ;)

Comment: uset timeout, redirect output to a file (maybe in /tmp, if it is on ram you get better performance) and tail -f that file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you always want the script to timeout after 5 minutes, you can simply use a block in a background process like this.  If you use `Ctrl+C` while it's running, the background process will also terminate:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    sleep 5m
    kill $$
} &

while true
do
    date
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thank you..this is a good answer but doesn't work in [my case](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MortezaLSC/Puplic/master/appl.sh)

Comment: ...Well, why not?

Comment: Owww...I saw your edited answer now...This is working absolutely...Thank you very much...

Comment: If you check via ps command , parent script and sleep are still running. Not recommended

Comment: @django It works as-described for me.  Run the script, Ctrl+C, run `ps`, and the background `sleep` process is terminated.

Answer (score 33):

The `timeout` utility that is a part of GNU coreutils does it for you:

```
timeout 5m bash script.sh
```

would terminate the script after 5 minutes of execution.

Comment: Pardon but there is a problem..while my script is running it shows me output..but in your case this is not do that..Imagin you have infinitive while loop that echo sth...when I do what you said it doesn't show me output and my machine hangs...

Comment: Works fine for me. I made a script consisting mostly of `while : ; do echo hello ; done` then ran `timeout 1s bash ./thatscript.sh` -- it printed "hello" a large number of times and terminated after about a second, as expected.

Comment: I tested it and My system broke down :), I don't know why!!!

Comment: @MortezaLSC I'm not sure what happens in your case.  This is a pretty standard utility designed for the very purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much @devnull . I used your answer and of course it is helping me...Thank you very much

Answer (score 17):

You get the PID with `PID=$$`.

What you want may be most easily achieved with the command `timeout`.

But you can run a background process, too:

```
(sleep $TIMEOUT && kill "$PID") &
```

Comment: Pardon but there is a problem..while my script is running it shows me output..but in your case this is not do that..Imagin you have infinitive while loop that echo sth...when I do what you said it doesn't show me output and my machine hangs...

Comment: @MortezaLSC I have given you two suggestions. What exactly have you done?

Comment: see Gnouc's answer, This is my [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MortezaLSC/Puplic/master/appl.sh) and please see my  update as well..Thank you very much

Comment: You see...It brings my script to background...while my script is running it shows sth in terminal runtime..

Comment: I think you still need to add `&` at the end to actually send it to the background. The brackets only start a subshell.

Answer (score 5):

You could change your loop to:

```
#!/bin/bash -
SECONDS=0
while ((SECONDS < 5*60))
do
  echo "line printed"
done
```

Or insert `((SECONDS < 5*60)) || exit` within your deepest loop.

`SECONDS` in `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash` is a special variables that gets incremented every second.

Comment: I think your answer is one of the best one..but I would be thankful and your answer would be accepted if you help me, This is my [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MortezaLSC/Puplic/master/appl.sh) . Where should I put your aswer here? Thank you very much

Comment: Your answer is the sth like Gnouc's answer and both are correct really...but in my case I confused...doesn't work

Comment: @MortezaLSC, your script is missing the `#! /bin/bash -` line so would be executed by `sh`.

Comment: No..I put the whole script into your while loop with `#!/bin/bash -` and doesn't work as well...please see blujay's answer.. It is working well

Comment: Didn't know such variable existed. As always, learned something new from your answers

Answer (score 4):

You can use a check condition:

```
#!/bin/bash

START=$(date +%s)

while [[ $(($(date +%s) - $START)) -lt 300 ]]
do
    #do something here
done

echo QUIT
```

**Explanation**

- `date +%s` get the time in seconds since epoch, we save it to `START` variable, mark start time of script.
- `[[ $(($(date +%s) - $START)) -lt 300 ]]`: we get current time (`date +%s` again) subtract to start time (which is saved in `START` variable).
- If the result is less than `300` (5 minutes), script continue running,
- If the result is equal to or greater than `300`, meaning script has run `5 minutes` since start time, we quit the `while` loop, script ends.

Comment: Thank you..My script has infinitive loop...if I put my whole script into your while loop do you think it works? Thank you

Comment: I think you must use my `while` loop instead of your infinitive loop to make it works. Can you give more details about your script?

Comment: +1   This is my [script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MortezaLSC/Puplic/master/appl.sh)

Comment: Your answer is the sth like `Stephane Chazelas`'s answer and both are correct really...but in my case I confused...doesn't work